# Verilog: detect pulses larger than tmax

Tags: verilog, detection, pulse

I have a question and I hope somebody can give me a hint to solve the problem.

I need a verilog code to make a signal "reset" goes high immediately if the period of input signal "in" is larger than tmax.

Signal "reset" should go low again at the next positive edge of "in" (if there is a next positive edge)

If the period of input signal "in" is smaller than tmax then signal "reset" should remain low.

Example 1.

```
tmax=100ns
period(in) = 80ns
```

- reset remains low all the time

Example 2.

```
tmax=100ns
period(in) = 130ns
```

- reset goes high 100ns after the first positive edge of "in"
- reset goes low at the next positive edge of "in", if there is a second pulse

[image: See attached image]

Where should I start?

Comment: Is this just for a Verilog testbench?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far and how it went wrong.

Comment: Hi toolic, no, it is actually a model that monitors the input signal "in" and outputs "reset" according to the description above. thank you!

Comment: first I tried implementing something like this:

`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module freq_meas (clk);
input clk;
real last_time, current_time, freq;
initial begin
last_time = 0.0;
freq = 0.0;
end
always@(posedge clk) begin
current_time = $realtime;
if (last_time > 0.0)
freq = 1.0e9 / (current_time – last_time);
last_time = current_time;
end
endmodule

Comment: the problem  is that this code has to wait for the next positive edge of the input "in" to measure the period and make a decision.
Imagine that "in" goes high and stays high. the code above will not react properly.
I need that if "in" goes high and stays high then "reset" should go high "tmax=100ns" after the positive edge of "in" and "reset" should also remain high.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  You will still have to do your check to see if Tmax is exceed, but you get a 1 timescale resolution between results.

```
always @ (*)
    begin
        while(1)
            begin
            current_time = $realtime; 
            if (last_time > 0.0) freq = 1.0e9 / (current_time - last_time); 
            last_time = current_time; 
            # 1;  // This allows for 1 timescale between loops.  If you leave
                  // this out, most simulators become non-responsive in the loop.
            end
    end
```